# How do I animate an SDF circle along a circular path using patches?

Tags: animation, math, spark-ar-studio

I have some SDF circles in spark ar studio that I need to animate in a circular path continuously. Is this possible? at the moment animating with patches I can only animate into a straight line using the x and y coords. How would I go about doing this?

Heres how it is currently set up.

[image: current animation setup]

Comment: Can you make it follow any parametric equation? In case you could use the equation of a circle

Comment: So the transition for the animation allows me to put start x and y and end x and y. There are lots of math patches but I'm now sure how I would get the animation to go around this path.

Comment: editied question with a screenshot of how its setup currently

Comment: Just realised I have an SDF translation patch also, perhaps this is better to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve a circular path using sine and cosine, by animating the transition values from 0 to 2*Pi (6.283). Here is an example:

[image]

There are some nice visualizations that explain how sine and cosine work, for example: https://www.reddit.com/r/visualizedmath/comments/7runef/unit_circle_visualization_of_sine_and_cosine/